# Docker-compose Adding Postgres Password

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm having issues accessing my postgres db from my remote machine.  I'm running docker-compose (django and postgres) from a digitalOcean droplet, so I need to be able to access the db from my mac.

I thought the below would work based on the outline of environment usage in docker-compose. Any help would be appreciated.

```
db:
  image: postgres
  ports:
    - "5555:5555"
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
web:
  build: .
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  links:
    - db
```

I'm trying to access the postgres db from pgadmin3 on port 5555, user:postgres, pass:mysecretpassword.

Comment: is pgadmin3 running on

Comment: Did you make postgres listen on port 5555 (does postgresql.conf have port set to 5555 and listen set to *) in container db? If you did, can you 'docker exec -it db bash'   and once in, 'psql -p 5555 -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres' ?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: what's your postgres image downloaded?

Comment: Same problem here. It looks like the environment variable `POSTGRES_PASSWORD `is being ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres uses port `5432` by default. You can map the `5432` port within the container to the host post of `5555` with a colon (as shown below).

```
db:
  image: postgres
  ports:
    - "5555:5432"
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
```

You're database is now accessible via port 5555.

I haven't used pgAdmin, but with `psql` the database can be accessed with...

```
psql -U postgres -h <your ip> -p 5555
```